# Set background image to body

Tags: joomla3.8

Is it possible to set background image to whole body?

I have tried to put into different files (`Extensions -> Templates -> Templates -> Details and Files`):
* css/custom-styles.tpl.css
* less/template-j4.less
* less/template.less

Nothing happens.

When I added it into `css/custom-styles.tpl.css` then in preview (`Extensions -> Templates -> Styles -> Edit`) the background is present, but not on the real site.

There is no body background image option in `... Styles -> Edit` either, only backgrounds for different parts (header, navigation, etc) or background color for whole body.

Version is 3.8.11

Comment: If you add it to the LESS files then you need to compile them first

Answer (score 1):

If you are correctly adding the property to the body element yet it does not display, it's possible the system cache is enabled or the template has a cache method in use and the changes to the custom-styles.tpl.css is not being used.

Also it may be that your bg property is being overridden by another. Use !important in the css instruction, and if still nothing appears, confirm that the path to the image is correct. Test with an absolute URL.

```
body {background: url(relative/path/to/image/bg.jpg) !important;}
```